# Objective-C/Xcode - password checking as user types

Tags: objective-c, events, textbox, keystroke

I would love to do something to reward the user visually when they match two text fields as they type. This is jQuery-esque, and I'm not sure if it's possible in Objective-C/Xcode. The key here is "AS THEY TYPE". Some web-based user account setup forms show a green checkbox when the password/confirmPassword (mainly because of the secure field formatting •••••) or email/confirmEmail form fields match or turn into a red "X" if the passwords lose their match.

Is there anything similar to an onKeystroke event in Objective-C/Xcode?

I'm willing to research and learn this. I just don't know how to correctly reference this type of functionality.

Comment: Should I edit it to reference Obj-C instead? I mean, I am using Xcode.

Comment: Mac or iOS? Please be a little more accurate ;)

Comment: iOS. Apparently I meant Cocoa Touch. lol. I believe the KeyUp event is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you want is in here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW1

What you're looking for is to implement the following in your text view and buffer the keystrokes and compare them with your text field.

```
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I appreciate this. I'll check it out.

Comment: I wouldn't go with keyup - the value can also change without a keyup-event, even without user interaction at all.

Comment: Overriding `keyUp:` requires subclassing `NSTextField`, and gets you the raw key events, which you will then need to process into text yourself -- a non-trivial task. The correct route here is the an [`NSTextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) or an [`NSTextDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/), and the text did/will change notification methods. @TSNev

Answer (score 1):

You could just observe the text field's value and in your callback, do your logic:

```
[self.textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.textField2 addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)textChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if ([self.textField1.text isEqualToString:self.textField2.text])
    {
        // passwords match
    }
    else
    {
        // passwords don't match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking after every character may consume too much web server bandwidth, try the "timer" check 1.4 seconds after user stopped typing.

```
@property IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *txtPassword;
@property NSThread *syncPasswordTimer;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(passwordType) name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:txtPassword];
}

    - (void)passwordType
    {
        [syncPasswordTimer cancel];
        syncPasswordTimer = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(passwordTimer) object:nil];
        [syncPasswordTimer start];
    }

    - (void)passwordTimer
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.4f];

        if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])
        {
            [NSThread exit];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"'%@'",txtPassword.stringValue);
            //DO THE CHECKING
        }
    }
```